# Query XML file using Multiple parameters

Tags: c#, xml, parameters

First a bit of Background. I'm hoping to build a program to de-skill the recognition of electronic components for an electronic manufacturer, this is the resistor section of the program. I've opted to write to XML but I am having issues querying the way I'd hoped.

This is a sample of my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    -<Resistors>
        -<Resistor>
            <ResistNo>RES144</ResistNo>
            <Value>2K 0.6w</Value>
            <Band1>Red</Band1>
            <Band2>Black</Band2>
            <Band3>Black</Band3>
            <Band4>Brown</Band4>
            <Band5>Brown</Band5>
         </Resistor>
     </Resistors>
```

To be usable at entry level I need to be able to query and filter the resistors by the Band colour, each resistor has a unique colour code so risk of getting two results is slim if not non-existent.

So far I have this code.

```
        var xmlResist = XDocument.Parse("resistor.xml");

        var elements = xmlResist.Element("Resistors")
                .Descendants("Resistor")
                .Where(x => x.Element("Band1").Value == txtBand1.Text)
                .Where(x => x.Element("Band2").Value == txtBand2.Text)
                .Where(x => x.Element("Band3").Value == txtBand3.Text)
                .Where(x => x.Element("Band4").Value == txtBand4.Text)
                .Where(x => x.Element("Band5").Value == txtBand5.Text);
```

From here I'm lost, I need to grab the values from "ResistNo" and "Value" and post them into txtResistNo.Text and txtValue.Text. I've been banging my head trawling the internet for something even close and the above code is as close as I have found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a `Select` :

```
var elements = xmlResist.Element("Resistors")
            .Descendants("Resistor")
            .Where(x => x.Element("Band1").Value == txtBand1.Text)
            .Where(x => x.Element("Band2").Value == txtBand2.Text)
            .Where(x => x.Element("Band3").Value == txtBand3.Text)
            .Where(x => x.Element("Band4").Value == txtBand4.Text)
            .Where(x => x.Element("Band5").Value == txtBand5.Text)
            .Select(x => new 
                        { 
                           ResistNo = (string)x.Element("ResistNo"), 
                           Value = (string)x.Element("Value") 
                        });
```

Also you can make if more efficient using one `Where` instead of five:

```
var elements = xmlResist.Element("Resistors")
            .Descendants("Resistor")
            .Where(x => x.Element("Band1").Value == txtBand1.Text &&
                        x.Element("Band2").Value == txtBand2.Text &&
                        x.Element("Band3").Value == txtBand3.Text &&
                        x.Element("Band4").Value == txtBand4.Text &&
                        x.Element("Band5").Value == txtBand5.Text)
            .Select(x => new 
                        { 
                           ResistNo = (string)x.Element("ResistNo"), 
                           Value = (string)x.Element("Value") 
                        });
```

If you want a single result use `First` or `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: Thank you I do love efficiency. I am however a little wet behind the ears. Would I be right in typing 
 txtResistNo.Text = elements.ResistNo

Comment: @K_Spec select returns multiple results.if you use First() after select then you can get one result and then you can use `txtResistNo.Text = elements.ResistNo`

Comment: Excellent thank you. I've just got to iron out the new exception now **System.Xml.XmlException was unhandled Message=Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1** I was fairly certain the XML file was well formed. Oh well. Thank you once again.